# What regular expression is required (for PHP preg_match)?

Tags: php, regex

One set of values in a MySQL table contains dimensions in varying formats, such as:

- 2140 × 910
- Ø500
- Ø600 × 1200
- 2000 × 1000 or Ø1500

These numbers are all dimensions in millimetres, and I would like a regular expression that can extract all the numbers (into an array, for example) so that I can convert them to inches and spew them back out in the same kind of format.

Using [regextester.com](http://www.regextester.com) I have tested the pattern `(\d+)` and it works fine, highlighting any group of digits within a string.

However, when I try and use this in my PHP code (below), the array of matches looks different to what I would expect.

```
$pattern = '/(\d+)/';
$string = '2140 &times; 910';
preg_match ($pattern, $string, $matches);

echo "<pre>";
print_r ($matches);
echo "</pre>";
```

This code outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2140
    [1] => 2140
)
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using [preg_match_all()](http://www.php.net/preg_match_all)

Answer (score 1):

[`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match) does only return the first match. If you want to get all matches, use [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/preg_match_all):

```
$pattern = '/(\d+)/';
$string = '2140 &times; 910';
preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

The output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "2140"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "910"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "2140"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "910"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I feel like a complete tool.